# Using vector in a class

Tags: c++, vector

I try to implement a heap class but I could not use vector in it.

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Heap {

public:
    Heap() {
    current_size = 0;
    }
private:
    int current_size;
    std::vector<T> array;
};
```

this program crashes when i try to run it. "project2.exe has stopped working. "

EDIT :

main function :

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {

    Heap<int> events;
}
```

Comment: vector needs templated arguments, for example  vector<int>

Comment: This isn't your whole program, is it?

Comment: The code above shouldn't build into an executable, e.g., because it is lacking a `main()` function. The code you posted looks OK (although I would initialize `current_size` in a member initializer list, assuming that `array.size()` isn't suitable...). The problem must be somewhere in code you haven't posted.

Comment: I'm going to assume there is a helluva lot more code in you're program than the above, which by-definition is a template and generates *nothing* without code that expands it.

Comment: @amaurea - you forgot the joke icon.. Of course it's not the whole program. It has to run before it can stop working. This code would _clearly_ not run as-is, without anything else..

Comment: i edited and i added main function.

Comment: @enhzflep - I guess nothing is self evident on the internet.

Comment: @Onur Neşvat: that main won't crash.

Comment: The code as posted works for me (but does nothing useful).

Comment: @amaurea - no, perhaps not. But seriously, was that meant to be a real question - or did you overlook the fact that, without a main it's going nowhere fast?

Comment: @enhzflep - It was not meant as a real question. It was meant to prompt him into posting the rest of his program.

Comment: complete program has too many lines and i do not want to confuse you. but i will add other codes to.

Comment: @amaurea - Aha. I see, thanks for the clarification. Guess that's 1 of the 'joys' of written communication - you don't get to hear the inflections in a person's voice as they ask questions - there's often no way to tell which word is being emphasised, unless it's done deliberately & explicitly. Without your last explanation, the intention of your question was anything but clear.

Comment: Before you get down-voted, add the smallest amount of code you can come up with that compiles and runs and demonstrates the problem. That means you have to do some work to cut out irrelevant parts. And if you're lucky, when you do that, you'll spot the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`"project2.exe has stopped working."` is a vague error, but is definitely occurring at run time. It's not helpful to you or to users of your program, so you need to implement better error handling.

When using vectors, run time errors usually occur from bad allocations (`std::bad_alloc` exception) and accessing elements in the vector which do not exist (`std::out_of_range` exception). Catch these exceptions to prevent your program from crashing, leaking memory and displaying the `"project2.exe has stopped working."` error message.

You can catch all the exceptions from your program by placing a try-catch block in the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        // put all your code here
        Heap<int> events;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& x)
    {
        // all std exceptions are caught here
        std::cerr << x.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

If your code contains `vector[subscript]`, it will not throw the `std::out_of_range` exception. If you don't need to be performance critical, replace it with `vector.at(subscript)` for the exception to be thrown.

Remember that error handling won't fix the problem, but can give you crucial hints leading to a solution. Also, you should consider using a debugger. They will tell you which line of code is causing the program to stop working.